# Getting SocketException: Connection reset with OHttp3 Client

Tags: java, httpclient, okhttp, quarkus

**Problem:**
I am using OkHttp3 Client in Quarkus project, but I am getting the following error in production:

> java.net.SocketException: Connection reset at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:186) ~[?:?] at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:140)

**Details**
My project is a type of middle layer that is calling the Backend APIs as a client, parses the response, and sends it back to the Front end. But sometimes, it throws the above exception when calling downstream APIs. In the case of a GET request, it retries two times, gets same exception and in third retry, a successful response is returned. But in POST request, it does not retries because of idempotency and fails in the first occurrence only.

*Code:*

```java
public class CustomOkHttpClient extends HttpClient {
    private OkHttpClient client;

    public Response callDownstream(HttpRequest clientRequest) {
        Response clientResponse = null;
        try {
            Call call = client.newCall(clientRequest);
            clientResponse = call.execute();
            return parseClientResponse(clientResponse, responseClass);
        } catch (final Exception exception) {
            logger.error("Exception occurred");
            throw exception;
        } finally {
            if (null!=clientResponse) {
                clientResponse.close();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

*Dependencies used:*
com.squareup.okhttp3:

- okhttp-urlconnection: 5.0.0-alpha.2
- logging-interceptor: 4.9.3
- mockwebserver: 4.9.0

**Ways tried**

- Used finally block to close the connection.
- Increased readTimeOut value of http client, but same error is happenning.

**How to proceed**

- What approach can I do further?
- Is this possible that the connection gets closed due to idle time period because no traffic is present during that time, and when after some long time, when request hit is made, it gets failed.

Comment: Do you really need the OKHttpClient? With Quarkus, this is the recommended HTTP Client: https://quarkus.io/guides/rest-client-reactive

Answer (score 0):

Set the connection pool’s keep alive duration to 60 seconds instead of the default 5 minutes.

```
OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
    .connectionPool(new ConnectionPool(5, 60, TimeUnit.SECONDS))
    .build()
```

Comment: Hi, but decreasing keep alive will also make more connections. Will that be feasible?